# Multiple SharePoint apps pointing to the same MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

I have more than 2 SharePoint apps and I want them to go to the same MVC Project with multiple Areas.

**SharePoint Apps:**

1. CRM
2. ProjectManagement

**MVC Areas**

1. base/CRM
2. base/ProjectManagement

I've configured the App Manifest to point to the correct URL in each of the SharePoint Apps:

```
Start Page: base/CRM
```

The problem's now are:

**1.** The web.config only contains 1 ClientId - but each SharePoint app needs its own ClientId - How do I get the correct ClientId to be picked up by the respective apps?

**2.** I've read that the TokenHelper.cs class stores data per session, so if someone was to jump from CRM to Project Management urls the session would contain the wrong Token information - How do I break this down to work with multiple apps?

Answer (score 0):

Both "problems" can only be solved by customizing the default SharePointContext.cs and TokenHelper.cs, because they are designed in this way.

No one stops you from modifying those files and use whatever clientID (or several IDs) you want depending on the conditions you should consider.